# How to export thousands of tables from large MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a MySQL database with tens of thousands of tables in a Wordpress multisite database, and I need to export several thousand of them so that I can import them into a new database.

I know that I can use mysqldump like this: "`mysqldump -u user -p database_name table_1 table_2 table_3 > filename.sql`", but what's the best way to make this scale? If it helps, the tables are named as follows: "`wp_blogid_tablename`" where blogid is the ID of the blog (there are around 1000 blogs to export), and tablename is one of many different tables names, for example:

```
wp_8_commentmeta
wp_8_comments
wp_8_links
wp_8_options
wp_8_postmeta
wp_8_posts
wp_8_referer_blacklist
wp_8_referer_visitLog
wp_8_signups
wp_8_term_relationships
wp_8_term_taxonomy
wp_8_termmeta
wp_8_terms
```

Comment: There are many WordPress plugins available which provide options for export the large MySQL data. [WP Database Backup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-database-backup/), You can google it and find it easily.

Comment: maybe this article can help you http://www.webhat.in/article/miscellaneous/shell-script-to-backup-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but not tested though -

```
mysqldump -u user -p database_name table_blogid_* > wp_blogid.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach might not work. Anyway, here is another solution for you -

```
mysqldump DBNAME $(mysql -D DBNAME -Bse "show tables like 'wp_8_%'") > wp_8.sql
```

Or you can try this, get the tables into a file first -

```
mysql -N information_schema -e "select table_name from tables where table_schema = 'databasename' and table_name like 'wp_8_%'" > wp_8_tables.txt
```

Now execute the sqldump script to export the tables -

```
mysqldump -u user -p database_name `cat wp_8_tables.txt` > wp_blogid.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried a similar approach but in the end I found that the mydumper command was easier.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution so far was to create a shell script with an array of numbers (the blog ids) that would loop and then used the `mydumper` command to export the SQL tables to a single directory. The command looked like this:

```
mydumper --database="mydbname" --outputdir="/path/dir/" --regex="mydbname\.wp_${i}_.*"
```

(the `${i}` is the blog id from the array loop)

Once completed I was able to load all of the sql files into the new database with the `myloader` command:

```
myloader --database="mynewdbname" --directory="/path/dir/"
```

Next challenge is to figure out how to DROP all of the exported tables from the original database...